# How to Program F10 Key to Lock My Windows 10 Dell PC

Tags: dell-inspiron, lock, function-keys

I own a Dell Inspiron 5555 laptop running Windows 10. It comes with two blank function keys, `F7` and `F10`. I often leave my computer temporarily and want to lock it, so I want to program `F10` to lock my PC. I have looked all over for the answer and have not found any method that works for me. `F7` is also an option if `F10` is a reserved key, but it has not worked for me either. Please let me know how I can accomplish this, or if it is not possible.

**NOTE:** I know that I can use `Windows Key`+`L`, but function keys are more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com) to assign a script to any key.

Just assign the following command to F10:

```
%windir%\System32\rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation
```

Comment: I have never heard of AutoHotKey before. I looked through the documentation and could not fix this error: `This line contains an unrecognized command.` It occurs in the line of code identical to the one you provided. What syntax am I missing?

Comment: @AlwaysBeProgramming it could be the % signs. Use the full path  c:\windows\system32...

Comment: Actually, rundll32 should be in your path, you probably can just drop the folders

Comment: I tried both of those options and neither worked. Just to clarify, what do you mean by "drop the folders"? I took it to mean to get rid of `C:\Windows\` `...`. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer by @keltari, the following script for [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) should work:

```
f10::Run rundll32.exe user32.dll`,LockWorkStation
```

Note that [per the official AutoHotKey documentation on the Run command](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Run.htm), commas must be escaped with a backtick ( ` ).

Comment: Great. Is there any way I can make it so that the command runs as an alternative function (e.g. F1=mute/unmute, F2=lower volume, etc.)?

Comment: If you do not wish to simply override `F10` to make it lock the PC, you can use a [key combo](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm) instead e.g. replace `f10` with something like `+f10` which would then lock the PC with `Shift + F10`. Unfortunately, using the actual `Function` or `Func` keys typically isn't possible in my experience.